# Determine if $A$ is diagonalizable. If $A$ is diagonalizable, find an invertible matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}AQ$ is a diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{align*}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathcal{M}_3[\mathbb{R}] 
\end{align*}

Determine if $A$ is diagonalizable.

If $A$ is diagonalizable, find an invertible matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}AQ$ is a diagonal matrix.

**Attempt**

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ (and therefore of $L_A$) is

\begin{align*}
f(\lambda)&=\det (A-\lambda I) \\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
1-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1-\lambda & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 3-\lambda
\end{vmatrix} = (3-\lambda) \begin{vmatrix}
1-\lambda & 1 \\
0 & 1-\lambda
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=(3-\lambda)(1-\lambda)(1-\lambda)
\end{align*}

and therefore the eigenvalues of $L_A$ are $\lambda _1=3$ and $\lambda _2=1$ with multiplicity 1 and 2, respectively. As

\begin{align*}
E_{\lambda_1}=\ker (L_A-\lambda I)=\left\lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} \right\rbrace 
\end{align*}

$E_{\lambda _1}$ is the solution space of the system of equations

\begin{align*}
    \left \{ \begin{matrix} -2x_1+x_2=0  \\ 
    -2x_2+2x_3=0
    \end{matrix}\right. 
\end{align*}

Comment: If you can find a basis of eigenvectors, make those the columns of a matrix $Q,$   then find $Q^{-1}.$ Of course, if there is not a basis of eigenvectors...